# Remove empty (date) brackets in bibliography

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-chicago

The `biblatex-chicago` package has a bug which displays empty brackets if

1. you specify "date=year" in `biblatex-chicago` call,
2. you have the date expressed in your `.bib` file such as "date =
   {2011-12-01}".

Result :

[image]

I informed the author of the package but I am afraid there will a long time before my version of `biblatex-chicago` on Debian sid will be fixed.

I am looking for a temporary fix.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[authordate,date=year]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{test_biblio.bib}
\begin{document}

\cite{test42}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

test_biblio.bib

```
@article{test42,
  author = {Author},
  title = {title},
  date = {2011-12-01},
  title = {Title},
  journal = {Journal},
  number = {88},
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An alternative to setting `date=year` is to delete the month and date info in the `date` field via Biber sourcemapping

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldset=month, null]
      \step[fieldsource=date, match=\regexp{([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})(-[0-9]{2})?}, replace={$1}]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple workaround could be to **not** specify "date=year" in `biblatex-chicago` call!

With the following MWE (package `filecontents` is only used to have `bib` file and TeX code together in one compilable MWE):

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{test42,
  author = {Author},
  title = {title},
  date = {2011-12-01},
  title = {Title},
  journal = {Journal},
  number = {88},
}
@article{test43,
  author = {Adams},
  title = {title},
  date = {2014},
  title = {Title},
  journal = {Journal},
  number = {88},
}
@article{test44,
  author = {Testerle},
  title = {title},
  date = {2015-12},
  title = {Title},
  journal = {Journal},
  number = {88},
}
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[%
  authordate,
% date=year % <=========================================================
]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}

\cite{test42}\nocite{*}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

you get the following result without errors and only one warning (comming from `filecontents`, okay):

[image: resulting bibliography]

Comment: I don't want the full date to be printed (only the year). I believed it was clear by my usage of `date=year`. All my bibliographical entries are automatically exported from Zotero (biblatex export). I cannot clean the entries before the export.

Comment: @ppr: Maybe you can clean them **after** export? A simple regular expression substitution with sed, perl, or python (pick one of your choice) should do the job.